# reading multiple images using open with visual studio

Tags: opencv

I am working on digital image processing. I have to run the code for 888 images in open cv using visual studio. Can anyone please help me with the source code to load multiple images from folder. I have a lesion and a mask for that and so totally 888 lesions which are jpg  and 888 masks which are tif images ,should be used. So can anyone help me as how to run code on these images directly from folder which consists both jpg and tif images.

Comment: what platform? handling file wildcards is different on Windows/Unix. ps this is nothign to do with openCV

Comment: I am doing it on a windows computer

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which flavor of OpenCV you're using ( the old C or the newer C++ ), but I am actually using some code like this :

```
cv::Mat srcImage1, srcImage2;
srcImage1 = cv::imread("//path/to/your/file/");
srcImage2 = cv::imread("//path/to/other/file/");
```

Do this in a for loop and work with the pictures as needed.

If the pictures are named using ascending numbers at the end for example, just build up a string ( using sprintf_n for example ) which includes the numbers.

Best,

Flo

Comment: Actually this is what I am doing for running the code for 1 image  IplImage* srcLesion = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\sbb97\\Documents\\195 set\\DT111507per45_CNP.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  IplImage* srcBorder = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\sbb97\\Documents\\195 set\\DT111507per45_CNP_mask.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  
 IplImage* whiteareamask = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(srcBorder), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);


 FindWhiteArea(srcLesion,srcBorder, whiteareamask);
 calcglobulefeatures(whiteareamask, srcBorder);
 calcdecilepercentages(srcBorder, whiteareamask);

Comment: How should i do it for 888 image set

Comment: With teh procedure you gave I have to change IplImage* every where to cv Mat and that would be  avery lengthy process how can I just run the code on sample set of images with IplImage* can u please hel me.

Comment: Do the file names have some kind of running number? Without that, it would be a bit more work to do that

Comment: There are 2 options. 1. You have pictures with ascending filenames : Run through all the pics in a for loop and build a filename string using sprintf_n. 2. The pictures have some names and are separated in folders : run through the content of the folder piece by piece. Visual C++ does not support that natively ( you have to install MinGW for example ). You also seem to be a total newbie using C ( because this question doesn't have anything to do with OpenCV specifically ), so I would recommend to rename your files ( using a batch ) and running through the files using indices.